# SSD Crash Randomly on Linux Mint 17

Tags: linux-mint, ssd, crash

I'm running Mint (17 Qiana 64bit) on a fresh install on a new laptop (Dell N5110) with a new Crucial MX100 SSD and twice now the whole system has frozen up. If I switch to a text terminal (as in ctrl-alt-f1) and attempt to login I get the message `end_request:I/O error, dev sda, sector XXXXXXXXX`

I've run both the Short offline and Extended offline tests from `gsmartcontrol`, and both have come back Completed without error.

The firmware on my SSD is MU01, I can't find anything on Crucial which says whether or not there's a firmware update available.

Any ideas what I should look at next? Is the SSD faulty? Driver issue? Laptop issue? Firmware issue? Don't really know where to start....

Comment: I have similar problem with my Windows 7 PC after a memory upgrade, have you done a memory test ?

Comment: Yeah - I've ran a full system test from the BIOS. Everything passed

Comment: Do you have tlp installed? Had the same problem with my Crucial MX100 and Mint 17. That solution helped me:
https://github.com/linrunner/TLP/issues/84